# Is it possible to convert struct type array to linkedlist in C/C++?

Tags: c, linked-list

I"m studying struct data structure in c/c++.

1 My program reads the data of the students(name,studentid, exam score 1,2) from the text file.

2 assign the data of the students to 'StuInfo' struct type array called 'students'.

3 Convert Struct type array 'StuInfo' to linkedlist.

From now on, I implemented 1 and 2, but I have difficulty achieving 3. I watched a lecture about linkedlist and practiced making linkedlist that contains int data. However, making linkedlist with struct type array is not easy.

I created method 'insertnode' and 'arraytolinkedlist' to achieve 3, but I"m uncertain whether my methods work as I intended.

Can we convert struct type array to linkedlist? It seems redundant, because converting struct array to linkedlist made of struct. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct StuInfo{
        char Name[10];
        int IDNo;
        int Exam[2];
        StuInfo *nextptr;
};

void PrintAllName(StuInfo Node){ // print name of the student in each struct StuInfo
        StuInfo *ThisPtr= &Node;
        while(ThisPtr!=NULL){
            printf("Name: %s \n",ThisPtr -> Name);
            ThisPtr=ThisPtr->nextptr;
        }   
}

void insertnode(StuInfo** node, StuInfo item){
     StuInfo *temp = new StuInfo;
     StuInfo* ptr;
     temp->IDNo=item.IDNo;
     temp->nextptr=NULL;

     if (*node == NULL)
         *node = temp;
     else {
         ptr = *node;
         while (ptr->nextptr != NULL)
             ptr = ptr->nextptr;
         ptr->nextptr = temp;
     }
}


StuInfo *arraytolinkedlist(StuInfo arr, int size){
  StuInfo *root = NULL;
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
     insertnode(&root,arr[i]);
  }
  return root;}

int main(void){
    struct StuInfo student[80];  // declare struct type array 'student'.
    int count = 0;
    int stunum = 0;
    int arrsize=sizeof(student)/sizeof(StuInfo);
    FILE *stuPtr = fopen("lab12_datafile.txt","r"); // read the name, studentid, exam1,2 score from textfile.
    while(!feof(stuPtr)
    {  
    fscanf(stuPtr,"%s%d%d%d",&student[count].Name,&student[count].IDNo,&student[count].Exam[0],&student[count].Exam[1]); // assign the data(name, studentid,exam1,2 score) in textfile to students array
    count++; 
    } 
   fclose(stuPtr);
   StuInfo *linkedlist= arraytolinkedlist(student,arrsize); // create linkedlist and store in the variable
   PrintAllName(linkedlist);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Yes, you will have to create a function to convert from one to another. Yes, it may be redundant.